# Define connection string without dependencies

Tags: wpf, connection-string

Recently I did a `WPF` application using `SQL` Database.Its connection string has been defined in `App.Config` file.

Also in setup I have added Required software (eg. `MSSQL Express`, `.netframework 4.5` etc).

Main concern is that it will be deployed in 100 standalone PC's at client side. According to the `SQL` Credential I need to change the Connection string, build every time and give them.

Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want any dependencies.

Here I would suggest you should go for `filesystem` database like `JSON` or `XML`.
You can give permission to restrict access. Also you can maintain data daily, weekly, monthly and yearly in folder wise as per requirement.